# Expectation of Ito Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose $X$ is an Ito process defined by 
$ dX = adt + b_tdB$ and $X_0 = 0$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion.
Ito process consists of two parts: one is deterministic and the other is random.
Is the expectation only decided by the deterministic part, i.e. $E(X_t)=at$ ? And why?
More generally, if $ dX = a_tdt + b_tdB$, is $E(X_t) = \int_0^ta_sds$ ?

Comment: Yes, essentially because increments of $B_t$ have zero mean. your function $b_t$ will come into play when you look for the expectation of $f(X)$ e.g. $X^2$ since $dB_{t} dB_{t} = dt$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Paul.